# Editing Local Host File to display .MHT file (local file on computer - NOT a web server)

Tags: localhost

I know that people like to edit the local host file to test websites that they are working on but I was wondering if the following scenario was possible: have browser open a locally stored `.MHT` file when I type in *www.URLADDRESS.com*.

I'm unsure how to edit the Host file in this respect because the `.MHT` file is stored locally on the computer. Let's say for example, the file is stored in `C:\temp\test.mht`

I only need this to work on my own computer.  I know I can easily just drag the `MHT` file into the browser to look at but I was curious if I could do it by typing in a `url` address even though it isn't coming from that site.

Comment: The host file can only map to addresses, not to files.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not. Even if you modify the host file so that the hostname of your choice points to localhost, you'll still need HTTP server software running to accept the browser's connection request and serve the file in response.